# WINDOWS How to find whether a memory address is static to the program

Tags: c++, windows

Like how the Cheat Engine shows a green color address when it is a static address, how would I find if it is a static address??

Comment: What do you mean by "static address"? Consider things like ASLR, for example.

Comment: When you build the linker generates a memory map telling you where everything is laid out in memory. After that anything that's static is by the grace of Crom.

Comment: It is when the value of the address program is the same each time the program is start

Comment: Slight correction, it's the same relative to the base address each time.